# Button alignment relative to button inside of another controller

Tags: html, angularjs

I have two buttons inside separate controllers.

```
<div ng-controller="aCtrl">
  <button class="addButton" ng-click="toggle()"> Add </button>
  <form ng-hide="myVar" ng-submit="submit()">
    <input ......
    <input ......
  </form>
</div>

<div ng-controller="bCtrl">
  <button class="EditButton" ng-click="toggle()"> Add </button>
  <form ng-hide="myVar" ng-submit="submit()">
    <input ......
    <input ......
  </form>
</div>
```

Note: Toggle just switches the hide/show bool in the back-end

As you can see when clicking the `Addbutton` it will show the form for `aCtrl` and `EditButton` for `bCtrl`. The result of the current layout is when Add Buttons form expands it pushes the EditButton down. I don't think this can be fixed with CSS as its the logical flow of the HTML.

I am looking for solutions that would allow me to have the buttons at the top in the flow of the page then the forms below.

for example I tried:

```
  <button ng-controller="aCtrl" class="EditButton" ng-click="toggle()"> Add </button>
  <button ng-controller="bCtrl" class="addButton" ng-click="toggle()"> Add </button>

<div ng-controller="aCtrl">
  <form ng-hide="myVar" ng-submit="submit()">
    <input ......
    <input ......
  </form>
</div>

<div ng-controller="bCtrl">
  <form ng-hide="myVar" ng-submit="submit()">
    <input ......
    <input ......
  </form>
</div>
```

Which doesn't seem to work.

Comment: when you specify ng-controller="aCtrl", a new controller instance of aCtrl is created and bootstrapped with that specific element. So as per to your latter code there will be 2 instance of aCtrl and 2 instance of bCtrl.
I feel CSS is the right option.  Can show a snap of before-toggle and after-toggle views or the working fiddle or something ?

Comment: CSS is definitely an option, even leveraging `position:absolute` I would encourage you to set up a https://plnkr.co/ to better display the issue of content moving when buttons are clicked

Comment: Note that your post does not have enough information. Make sure that your convey the sufficient information so that we can help you out in this

Comment: How would the add button bind to the aCtrl and edit button be bind to the bCtrl if specified out of ng-controller?

Comment: Just a question. As per your approach, both Add and Edit screens can be opened at a time as the "show or hide" variable is different for each controller. 
Is this behavior ok for you? if yes please go ahead with solutions proposed below by @Arber Sylejmani.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that [`ng-hide`](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.20/docs/api/ng/directive/ngHide) hides the content with a `display: none` that causes the space occupied by the element to collapse.
You need `visibility: hidden` that also hides the element, but keeps the space.

Therefore, use [`ng-class`](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.20/docs/api/ng/directive/ngClass) instead of `ng-hide`:

```
<div ng-controller="aCtrl">
  <button class="addButton" ng-click="toggle()"> Add </button>
  <form ng-class="{ 'hidden' : myVar }" ng-submit="submit()">
    <input ......
    <input ......
  </form>
</div>

<div ng-controller="bCtrl">
  <button class="EditButton" ng-click="toggle()"> Add </button>
  <form ng-class="{ 'hidden' : myVar }" ng-submit="submit()">
    <input ......
    <input ......
  </form>
</div>
```

and the CSS

```
.hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Here is a live sample:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function aCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.myVar = true;
    $scope.toggle = function () {
      $scope.myVar = !$scope.myVar;
    }
}

function bCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.myVar = true;
    $scope.toggle = function () {
      $scope.myVar = !$scope.myVar;
    }
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<section ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="aCtrl">
    <button class="addButton" ng-click="toggle()"> aCtrl.Add </button>
    <form ng-class="{ 'hidden' : myVar }" ng-submit="submit()">
      <input type="text" value="aCtrl.form">
    </form>
  </div>

  <div ng-controller="bCtrl">
    <button class="EditButton" ng-click="toggle()"> bCtrl.Add </button>
    <form ng-class="{ 'hidden' : myVar }" ng-submit="submit()">
      <input type="text" value="bCtrl.form">
    </form>
  </div>
</section>
```

As you can see, the `bCtrl.Add` button remains in place, regardless whether `aCtrl.form` is visible or not.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done via css only, just wrap the two in a div with position: relative and then add position:absolute to addButton and editButton together with top/left/right positioning values.

```
<div class="formContainer">
 <div ng-controller="aCtrl">
  <button class="addButton" ng-click="toggle()"> Add </button>
  <form ng-hide="myVar" ng-submit="submit()">
    <h1>Add form</h1>
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
  </form>
</div>
<div ng-controller="bCtrl">
  <button class="editButton" ng-click="toggle()"> Edit </button>
  <form ng-hide="myVar" ng-submit="submit()">
    <h1>Edit form</h1>
     <input type="text">
     <input type="text">
  </form>
 </div>
</div>
```

and css:

```
.formContainer {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.addButton {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 40px;
}

.editButton {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Here's a working demo: [Plunker CSS Only](https://plnkr.co/edit/w6tJdqagrnX80DBzj5fJ?p=preview)

There's another way, put them in a parent controller, which would hold the logic for toggling between the forms and then each form have their own controller for their respective functionalities.

Here's a working demo of the second version:  [Plunker with parent Controller](https://plnkr.co/edit/K4zIxo9VJzwiI2MhvaMn)

Answer (score -1):

Here is example as u mentioned in your post. u can keep button outside of your controllers

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('aCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.myVar = true
}]);  
myApp.controller('bCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  $scope.myVar = true;
}]);  

function getscope(ctrlName) {
    var sel = 'div[ng-controller="' + ctrlName + '"]';
    return angular.element(sel).scope();
}

function showForm(ctrlName) {
    var $scope = getscope(ctrlName);
    $scope.myVar = !$scope.myVar;
    $scope.$apply();
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.min.js"></script>

<section ng-app="myApp">
<button class="addButton" onclick="showForm('aCtrl')"> aCtrl.Add </button>
<button class="EditButton" onclick="showForm('bCtrl')"> bCtrl.Add </button>


  <div ng-controller="aCtrl">
    
    <form ng-hide="myVar" ng-submit="submit()">
      <input type="text" value="aCtrl.form">
    </form>
  </div>

  <div ng-controller="bCtrl">
    
    <form ng-hide="myVar" ng-submit="submit()">
      <input type="text" value="bCtrl.form">
    </form>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score -2):

Is having two controllers is your requirement ?

You can have a separate controller of the button for eg. btnCtrl and toogle the value using a `$rootscope` variable. As follows.

```
 <button ng-controller="btnCtrl" class="EditButton" ng-click="toggle()"> Add </button>
  <button ng-controller="btnCtrl" class="addButton" ng-click="toggle()"> Add </button>

<div ng-controller="aCtrl">
  <form ng-hide="$root.myVar" ng-submit="submit()">
    <input ......
    <input ......
  </form>
</div>

<div ng-controller="bCtrl">
  <form ng-hide="$root.myVar" ng-submit="submit()">
    <input ......
    <input ......
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: @mistalis thank you for your comment. Can you please suggest a more elegant approach with the above constraints ?

Comment: [*@JoseRuiSantos answer*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41758108/4927984) is highly cleaner.